# illegal IP for socket?

Tags: sockets, ip

Is there an IP 0.0.0.0 for a socket? or 48.0.0.0 for a socket?

Comment: This might help http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_assigned_/8_IPv4_address_blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand your question. If you elaborate I'll edit this answer.

Binding a listening socket to `0.0.0.0` makes it listen on all interfaces. If you bind to a particular IP address (`127.0.0.1`, for a common example) you'll only listen on that **one** instance (in this case, the `localhost` loopback interface).

You don't bind client sockets, you connect them. In this case, I don't think you can connect to `0.0.0.0` (in any case, it wouldn't be very useful).

I don't think there's anything special about `48.0.0.0`. It looks like it's owned by Prudential Insurance, actually.

If this isn't the question you're asking, you need to edit your question to ask it properly.

Comment: Also loopback. What question were you asking?